# Modify core search results to display custom property

Tags: xslt, search-results

I am trying to modify the core search results webpart in SP2010.
Ive created a managed property named: ExternalContactsCompany

I then added a `<Column name="ExternalContactsCompany"/>` section to the fetched properties inside the webpart properties.

Next i added the following XSL:

```
TEST <xsl:value-of select="externalcontactscompany"/>
```

All i can see is "TEST". The last part is not showing anything.

And yes, the column is filled !

Comment: where/how would i customize/style the layout of the results once I implement this solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your XSLT with the following piece of code (don't forget to backup ;))

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/> 
<xsl:template match="/"> 
  <xmp><xsl:copy-of select="*"/></xmp> 
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Publish the page and verify which XML is available from the search engine.
If the column "ExternalContactsCompany" is not available - you do something wrong.

Comment: This isn't realy an answer to my question. But it helped me to find the solution.

Comment: Fredrik, if the answers to the problem was something else, please share it. You're allowed to answer your own question :)

Comment: The xslt mentioned by Sven showed me the full XML. This way we saw that the property was empty. We checked the setting on the managed property "‘Reduce storage requirements for text properties by using a hash for comparison" and then my value wasn't empty anymore !

Answer (score 0):

I wrote in my blog a guide to create a new crawlable property and a guide to modify the xsl that display the results list: http://salvatoredifaziosharepoint.blogspot.it/2012/04/how-to-modify-sharepoints-result-page.html